# How do I dynamically focus on input element at run time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I want to dynamically focus on input element at run time. I will pass input name runtime and then it should focus the input accordingly.

This is code for input element

```
<input type="text" id="txtNameOfEmp" data-bind="event: { blur: ValidateName.bind($data,txtNameOfEmp) } " />
```

Then in my view model i am trying to focus as below

```
    self.ValidateName = function (val) {
        var inputName = val.id;

            // some logic for validation
            alert("Name is not valid");
            $("'#" + inputName + "'").focus()

    };
```

I get error

```
JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#txtNameOfEmp'
```

How to focus dynamically?

**Update1**

I have also tried below but it doesnt give error but doesnt set any focus as well

```
$(inputName).focus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man... there is a mistake in your code as I see it:

remove the single quotes:

```
use $("#"+inputName).focus();
```

Comment: Wow it works but dont understand why it should not work with single quotes. Because normally if we want to focus we write $('#txtName').focus()

Comment: Yes.. it works for single quote but both are valid uses. But you will surely have problem concatenating two chars other than two strings ..

Answer (score 2):

You've got too many quotes. You don't need any as you've wrapped your id in a variable.

Try this:

```
$("#" + inputName).focus()
```

Comment: i have already tried this as well but it doesnt set any focus

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
  $(inputName).focus();
```